# Play framework 2.3 debug

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.3

I just switched to play 2.3, and I am having trouble getting the debug mode to work. From the console I am running 'activator -jvm-debug 9999', and then from inside intellij I am using the default play2 debug configuration. However, it doesn't seem to work and I'm getting this readout in the debug console:

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52698', transport: 'socket'
[info] Set current project to modules (in build file:/Users/Grillz/IdeaProjects/titan-play-test/.idea/modules/)
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)

This used to work great in play 2.2.3, is there additional config i need to be doing? I can't seem to find any changes in the migration documentation. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild Idea project (activator console > `idea with-sources=yes`)?

Comment: Yeah that was I one of the first things I tried. Im not sure what changed, but the play framework guys are saying its on the Intellij crew